# How to pad only letters to right for number type input tag, excluding the arrows

Tags: html, css

When I try applying `padding-right` to an `input` of type **number** the padding is applied to the input including the arrows. But, my intention is to have some spacing between the arrows and the text.

**CODE**

```css
.steps {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" class="steps">
```

This results in the text really close to the arrows:

[image]

How can I have spacing between letters and arrows? It's like I want `letter-spacing` only to the last letter.

**NOTE**: To be clear, the question may seem duplicate, but the original answer doesn't provide solution for cross browser. It only gives a fix for Chrome and suggests to hide arrows for FireFox, which is not an option for me.

Comment: To be clear, the question may seem duplicate, but the original answer doesn't provide solution for cross browser. It only gives a fix for Chrome and suggests to hide arrows for FireFox, which is not an option for me.

Comment: There is no cross browser fix currently unless you use some sort of js plugin - there is not much you can do with these arrows - as you have seen different browsers style them completely differently

Comment: @Pete Ok Thanks

Comment: Here's an example of something someone has done: https://codepen.io/komarovdesign/pen/PPRbgb